# Access violation writing location after bubble sort

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, bubble-sort

```
/*
for i=0 to n-1 do
   for j=n to  i+1 do
      if (vector[j-1]<vector[j])
         swap(vector[j-1],vector[j])
      end_if
   end_for
end_for
*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int *v) {
    int n = 19;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("<%d> ", v[i]);
    }
    _asm
    {
        mov esi, v 
        mov ebx, n 
        mov ecx, 0
        loopi:
            mov edi, esi
            mov edx, n
        loopj:
            mov eax, [edi + 4 * 18]
            mov esp, [edi + 4 * 19] 
            cmp eax, esp
        jb no_swap
            xchg eax, [edi + 4 * 19] // swap
            mov [edi + 4 * 18], eax 
       no_swap :
            sub edi, 4 
            dec edx
            cmp edx, ecx
            ja loopj
            inc ecx
            cmp ecx, ebx
            jb loopi
    }
    printf("%d\n", v[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }
}
int main() {
    int vector[20] = {1,3,4,5,2,10,13,15,6,9,20,7,11,19,8,12,18,14,17,16};
    bubbleSort(vector);
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",vector[i]);
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

The problem comes after sorting the vector, if I try to do anything it crash and shows access violation message. I tried to debug it but I cant find any problem, the vector sorts fine, I didnt access to any memory out of v. Can you help me please?

Comment: Where is the fault happening precisely? Are you respecting the calling convention your compiler is using?

Comment: I do have to wonder why you would bother to optimize a bubble sort with assembly...  Being about the slowest sorting algorithm that there is, I'd trust that the compiler will do just fine on its own; optimizing to assembly would be better suited to something more complex.

Comment: Just glancing at your code, I suspect that the problem isn't your sort... the problem is more likely that you do not tell the compiler which registers you clobber.  As a result, it is expecting certain values to still be what they were before your assembly code ran and then it is operating on them, creating the access violation.

Comment: @MargaretBloom it happens if I do whatever after the block _asm.

Comment: You are destroying _ESP_ in your code without saving it. As a quick hack you could always save _ESP_ to a variable and then restore it. So in the _C_ code add `int espsave;` then at the top of the assembler template do `mov espsave, esp` and at the bottom restore it with `mov esp, espsave`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very much, now it works.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It was an exercise to learn some x86 assembly, I'm studying Computer Engineering.